# Unable to locate package kubectl when installing the kubectl kubeadm for kubernetes installation

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create a high availability cluster using the kubeadm tool. And I am trying to install the tools that specified in the pre-requistics of kubeadm installation. When I am running `sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl` , I am getting the error like the following,

```
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package kubelet
E: Unable to locate package kubeadm
E: Unable to locate package kubectl
```

**My Attempt**

I am following the following official documentation for preparing the nodes from kubernetes.io. I am refering the following link for that,

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#before-you-begin

Ans when I am continuing with following commands as described in the official documentation,

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https curl
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main EOF
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
```

**Updates**

When I tried the answer from Mr.Tummala, I am getting the error like the following,

```
W: Failed to fetch https://apt.kubernetes.io/dists/kubernetes-xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve host: apt.kubernetes.io
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

But result like unable to locate the package.

Comment: Check if this file was created :
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list

Answer (score 10):

See if the below steps are doing the trick for you.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https curl
echo "deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
```

Comment: Yes. I tried. When I tried the echo command , I am getting the error `W: Failed to fetch https://apt.kubernetes.io/dists/kubernetes-xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve host: apt.kubernetes.io
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Comment: ah then it might be a firewall issue which is blocking access to apt.kubernetes.io check that out

Comment: Thank you for your  response sir. When I tried the comment to check the firewall status by using `sudo ufw status`. It showing inactive.

Comment: When I tried to ping apt.kubrentes.io, its pinging also.

Comment: try `wget https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/kubernetes-xenial/InRelease`

Comment: Yes. Itried. this one is working. And kubectl kubelet is also working. Will you modify your answer to include this please ? I can accept this as answer. Please update this in answer.

Comment: so basically for you, `apt.kubernetes.io` isn't working and `packages.cloud.google.com` is working, could you please say where the VM is running so that we can troubleshoot this weird issue? if you see in other network `apt.kubernetes.io` just redirects to `https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/`

Comment: VM is running on premise machine. Not in cloud.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204047/discussion-between-tummala-dhanvi-and-jacob).

Comment: I get the error that it's not signed.   `W: GPG error: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A030B21BA07F4FB`

Comment: found a workaround for the public key issue... download it yourself,  (its down a bit on the page) `https://devkimchi.com/2018/06/05/running-kubernetes-on-wsl/`

Answer (score 6):

I would refer to the official documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#installing-kubeadm-kubelet-and-kubectl

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl
```

Then,

```sh
sudo curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
```

Finally

```sh
sudo apt-get update
# Optionally, view versions with 
# sudo apt-cache show kubectl
sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -` then `sudo bash -c 'cat <<EOF >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list`
`deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main`
`EOF'` after it just run `sudo apt-get update` and then `apt-cache policy kubelet | head -n 20` now you can try to install kubectl and kubeadm again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I followed the above steps and still had problems with the gpg key. So, if by chance, during the update, you get the message:

```
W: GPG error: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY "GPG_KEY"
```

copy the GPG_KEY and run the command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys "GPG_KEY"
```

and then run sudo apt update -y again.

then:

```
sudo apt-get update
# Optionally, view versions with 
# sudo apt-cache show kubectl
sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
```

Answer (score 0):

See if the below solution works for you, it worked for me

```bash
sudo su -
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
echo "deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
exit
```